# Multiplexing with or without transistors

Tags: arduino, led, multiplexer

I'm doing something in where I need to multiplex 6 7-segment displays. About doing it, I found things like this:

[image]

And things in where the same thing is done without the transistors, just by connecting the cathodes directly to pins of the microcontroller. What's the difference? When should I need the transistors? Is it because the microcontroller couldn't handle current for all the LEDs?

I'm using an Arduino with an ATMEGA328, if that's needed for something.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but you might want to look at the MAX7219 chip to drive the LEDs. Check this [tutorial for using it with the arduino](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/LEDMatrix).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many MCUs won't handle the current for seven segments unless a transistor is used. You might be OK with the AVR (40 mA maximum per output, IIRC), but you need to check it, and the total current.

Comment: While 40mA should be enough for a 7-segment display (maximum of 5mA per LED, set by the series resistors) only one digit will be on at a time with this multiplexed control. That means that the total 200mA chip max isn't a factor, but because each digit is only on 1/6 of the time (because you are multiplexing 6 digits) the effective brightness is reduced to 1/6 of what it would normally be at 5mA.